# Concerning Tetrahedra

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, three-dimensional

As a pyramid with a triangular base, the volume of a tetrahedron, like all pyramids, is $(1/3)*BH$, where $B$ is the base area and $H$ is the height.

If one had $3$ square $45$ degree pyramids (square base), it is not too hard to see how one could slice two of the pyramids with a single slice (each) and then reassemble the $5$ pieces into a rectangular block that has the same square base and a height $H$.

So, if one had $3$ equal size regular tetrahedra, how many slices are needed to create the $N$ pieces needed to reassemble them into a triangular prism of height $H$, where $H$ is the height of the initial tetrahedra?

NOTE: One might answer:  "$N-2$ slices", but I need a bit more information than that.

Comment: Are we dealing with regular tetrahedra, i.e. with equilateral triangles as faces?

Comment: @FlorianF Yes. Edited.

Comment: Looks impossible to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> that it is impossible.

The question is an instance of [Hilbert's Third Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem).

> Any triangular prism has a zero Dehn invariant because you can pair up the top and bottom edges and their contributions to the Dehn invariant cancel (the angles add to $\pi$ radians), and similarly the three vertical edges together cancel.
>
>  The set of three tetrahedra has a non-zero Dehn invariant. The angle between its faces is not a nice fraction of $\pi$ radians, so cannot cancel.
>
>  Therefore they cannot be transformed into each other through dissection.